# PHPExcel getCalculatedValue() returns wrong answer when cell contains formula with special characters in it

Tags: php, phpexcel

here is a piece of my code I'm having trouble with

```
$where = "O".$i;
$formula = '=IFERROR(IF(OR(C'.$i.'="výzva",C'.$i.'="string2"),E'.$i.'," ")," ")';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($where, $formula);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($where)->getCalculatedValue();
```

I used official debugging function `testFormula($sheet,$cell)` and I noticet that word "výzva" is being problem during evaluation. I have my script encoded in UTF-8, to that cells with special characters are properly written in .xls file I'm creating at the end. When setCellValue with formula, in .xls file answer is correct but is there any way to get calculated value from this type of formula? Thanks for advice